# creating JSON object without using a list

Tags: json, lint

I want to be able to create a JSON object so that I can access it like this.

```
education.schools.UNCC.graduation
```

Currently, my JSON is like this:

```
var education  = {
    "schools": [
        "UNCC": {
            "graduation": 2015, 
            "city": "Charlotte, NC", 
            "major": ["CS", "Spanish"]
        },
        "UNC-CH": {
            "graduation": 2012,
            "city": "Chapel Hill, NC"
            "major": ["Sociology", "Film"]
        }
    ],
    "online": {
        "website": "Udacity",
        "courses": ["python", "java", "data science"]
    }
};
```

When I go to Lint my JSON, I get an error message.
I know I can reformat my object to access it like this (below), but I don't want to do it this way. I want to be able to call the school name, and not use an index number.

```
education.schools[1].graduation
```

Comment: That isn't JSON, it is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects have named keys. Arrays are a list of members.

Replace the value of `"schools"` with an object. Change `[]` to `{}`.

Comment: Replace [] to {} ? But If you have a Array of schools, you need to use [{ "school1" .... "school2" }]
You can access with education.schools[1], after this?

Comment: @rguerra — If you want an array of schools, then yes, you would do something like that. The question specifically says that is not what is desired: "I want to be able to call the school name, and not use an index number."

Answer (score -1):

This is your JSON corrected.
Your JSON is invalid.

```
{
    "schools": [
        {
            "UNCC": {
                "graduation": "2015",
                "city": [
                    "CS",
                    "Spanish"
                ],
                "major": [
                    "CS",
                    "Spanish"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "UNC-CH": {
                "graduation": "2012",
                "city": [
                    "Chapel Hill",
                    "NC"
                ],
                "major": [
                    "Sociology",
                    "Film"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "online": {
        "website": "Udacity",
        "courses": [
            "python",
            "java",
            "data science"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Explanation**:

1. "city": "Chapel Hill, NC" -> this is a array with 2 values "*Chapel* *Hill*" and "*HC*", like you do with major and courses.
2. The Schools array, you need to use this sintaxe to construct a array [{

http://adobe.github.io/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html

Comment: You have a invalid JSON. You want work with a invalid JSON and this is impossible. You need to construct a valid JSON first.

Comment: My point is not that I don't know what you are trying to do (I do), but that other people don't. Pure code is not a good answer. You have to explain what the problem was and how to fix it in a way that people can understand.

Comment: In other words: Answers should include explanations and not be games of spot-the-difference.